# Store values from dynamically created inputs to a PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page that allows the user to add and remove text fields to a form using JavaScript.

Text fields are named `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, etc. and depends on how many fields the user has added

I'm trying to store all the values from my text fields into one Php variable;

I understand that i need to store them into an array first and then use `implode()`, but how can i specify how many inputs there are within my Php code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the best way to approach this is to use array-named input, as shown in the following [example in the PHP docs](http://php.net/language.variables.external#example-108):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Nombre:  <input type="text" name="personal[nombre]" /><br />
    Email:   <input type="text" name="personal[email]" /><br />
    Cerveza: <br />
    <select multiple name="cerveza[]">
        <option value="warthog">Warthog</option>
        <option value="guinness">Guinness</option>
        <option value="stuttgarter">Stuttgarter Schwabenbräu</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit me!" />
</form>
```

You could use the very same name for each of the user added fields, as in:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" name="fields[]" />
<input type="text" id="field2" name="fields[]" />
```

And then just use implode as required:

```
$imploded_fields = implode(', ', $_POST['fields']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

1. You can use cookies. Use `PHP $_COOKIE` to get it. [For help](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp).
2. You can use `html hidden input fields` - `<input type="hidden" value="">` and can store actual number of fields in it.

*But, Diego Agulló is better one*

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden field and initialize it with 1 if on option is already open(field1). And increase the the value of counter while increasing the value of fields and vise verse. On submit you will find the total fields added.

Thanks